# Skipping of For loop while using goto

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my code for finding a palindrome of a string.
The initial execution works perfectly.
But when it comes to executing the program again, it goes to the label, and skips the cin statement and directly executes everything and finally reaches the end.
This didn't happen when I used it in c++ 6.0, but happens in visual studio 2015
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char string[100], ch;
    int x, i, j, flag = 0;
label:
    cout << "Enter a string. Max Length 99 : ";
    cin.getline(string, 100);
    x = strlen(string);
    cout << "Checking For Palindrome...........";
    for (long i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i)
    {
        cout << "";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0, j = x - 1; i < x / 2; ++i, --j)
    {
        if (string[i] == string[j])
            continue;
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        cout << "The String You Entered Is Not A Palindrome";
    else
        cout << "The String You Entered Is A Palindrome";
    cout << "\nDo you want to execute again? (Y/N)";
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
         goto label;
    else
         cout << "See You Later :)";
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but a general comment. **DONT** use `goto`. Ever.

Comment: @Sty I wouldn't say *ever*, but 99.9% of cases are better solved with a loop construct instead.

Comment: Wrap that sucker in a `while`. `goto` isn't buying you anything here.

Comment: There is no "c++ 6.0". You must be referring to some hopelessly outdated compiler which accepted this broken code. It's a good thing you have started to use a compiler from this century. Now make `main` return `int` and use `std::string` instead of arrays. Get rid of `
using namespace std;` and `#include "stdafx.h"`. Use descriptive variable names. Then eliminate the `goto` and turn it into a loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `goto` but it's not the culprit, you need to flush the new line char after `cin >> ch;` i.e. `cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: Check your `flag` variable. You have to reset it before `goto label;`.